# Nativescript - Angular Change background-color of Layouts with ns-dark mode inside components

Tags: sass, nativescript, nativescript-angular, android-darkmode

I have a question about how to use the ns-dark class in nativescipt together with Layouts.

```
GridLayout {
  background-color: light(background);
  @at-root .ns-dark & {
     background-color: dark(background);
  }
}
```

When I define the css class in _app-common.scss its working fine but NOT when I define the class in a x.component.scss. If its defined there it will always take the light class.

I want to do the same for a e.g.  background color, but the ns-dark properies are not applied.
I am testing under nativescript 6.3 Angular with Android.

Comment: Are you saying the background color is not applied to GridLayout but it works only with label?

Comment: Yes the GridLayout still gets the light color instead of the "dark" background color. The code works fine on a label but I need it to work on Layouts...

Comment: Can you show what you have in your HTML

Comment: <DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
    <GridLayout        
        class="search-bar"
        dock="top"
        columns="*,2*"
        rows="auto"
    >
        <Label>(...)</Label>
        <Button>(...)</Button>
    </GridLayout>
 (...)
</DockLayout>
I am not able to set the backgroud color of the GridLayout dependend on dark mode.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine on my end, checkout the [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=coPP8B), if you have issues please update the Playground and share the link.